# Docker image is not found after build

Tags: docker, podman

I just installed Podman on MacOS, because Docker was using a lot of CPU. I [followed the steps](https://podman-desktop.io/docs/migrating-from-docker/using-podman-mac-helper) to install `podman-mac-helper` so my docker commands now use Podman for container build/run.

The first time around, my image built successfully, and I was able to run it. I'm building like this:

```
docker build --tag ${IMAGE}:${TAG} --load src
```

... and running it like this:

```
docker run --rm -p 9090:8080 -e PORT=8080 ${IMAGE}:${TAG}
```

I'm not running these commands manually - they're in shell scripts, so there's no risk of a typo.

After the first, successful, run, I wanted to increase the resources for the Podman machine, so I deleted it, and created a new one with more resources:

```
podman machine rm
podman machine init --cpus 2 --memory 4096 --disk-size 20
podman machine start
```

(I also stopped it again, and set it to rootful with `podman machine set --rootful`.)

After building, I don't see the image I just built:

```
$-> ./bin/build.sh 
Building image... platescanimage:python
[+] Building 1934.4s (12/12) FINISHED                                                                                              docker-container:default
 => [internal] booting buildkit                                                                                                                        5.4s
 => => pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1                                                                                                     4.5s
 => => creating container buildx_buildkit_default                                                                                                      0.9s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.05kB                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11-slim                                                                                    1.4s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 105B                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.11-slim@sha256:8fcf215ec209b0cba4048197d3a78544faa69561b03a35528899fd9b93fe2990                              5.5s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:3.11-slim@sha256:8fcf215ec209b0cba4048197d3a78544faa69561b03a35528899fd9b93fe2990                              0.0s
 => => sha256:4fd6dc6aab4113722a2f7fc6fa7b590d4d6d856e360692f374d50adb6a17c576 243B / 243B                                                             0.1s
 => => sha256:224bef87b19ec58d6d1f9eb930c06d759d968e2777da29ae8265cd3d95957a7d 3.39MB / 3.39MB                                                         0.2s
 => => sha256:641dc97a55baa99911dcbdbdb0a6e9c857b8c238e3bdc45b173af14c8b61192c 12.83MB / 12.83MB                                                       1.0s
 => => sha256:bf3336e84c8e00632cdea35b18fec9a5691711bdc8ac885e3ef54a3d5ff500ba 3.50MB / 3.50MB                                                         0.6s
 => => sha256:a803e7c4b030119420574a882a52b6431e160fceb7620f61b525d49bc2d58886 29.12MB / 29.12MB                                                       1.1s
 => => extracting sha256:a803e7c4b030119420574a882a52b6431e160fceb7620f61b525d49bc2d58886                                                              2.9s
 => => extracting sha256:bf3336e84c8e00632cdea35b18fec9a5691711bdc8ac885e3ef54a3d5ff500ba                                                              0.3s
 => => extracting sha256:641dc97a55baa99911dcbdbdb0a6e9c857b8c238e3bdc45b173af14c8b61192c                                                              0.6s
 => => extracting sha256:4fd6dc6aab4113722a2f7fc6fa7b590d4d6d856e360692f374d50adb6a17c576                                                              0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:224bef87b19ec58d6d1f9eb930c06d759d968e2777da29ae8265cd3d95957a7d                                                              0.2s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                      4.7s
 => => transferring context: 174.77MB                                                                                                                  4.7s
 => [2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                 0.2s
 => [3/6] COPY requirements.txt ./                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [4/6] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt                                                                                         137.1s
 => [5/6] COPY . ./                                                                                                                                    0.8s
 => [6/6] COPY ./application_default_credentials.json ./                                                                                               0.0s 
 => exporting to docker image format                                                                                                                1783.6s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                              205.3s 
 => => exporting manifest sha256:5bd1cba5629576031479784189cf61571f7a922112b7c229491b9ba9e56e0563                                                      0.0s 
 => => exporting config sha256:1c63a3be325def7231046ed1ac2a0b47b045392002f2075ea229a1d90e2b6a89                                                        0.0s 
 => => sending tarball                                                                                                                              1578.3s

$-> docker images -a
REPOSITORY      TAG               IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
moby/buildkit   buildx-stable-1   9291fad3b41c   6 weeks ago   173MB
```

Note the image is called **platescanimage:python**, and that doesn't appear in the `docker images` output. (Nor does it appear in `podman images`.)

There are also no errors in the build. The only thing I've noticed is that the first successful build had an extra line of of output, that said "importing to Docker":

```
...
 => exporting to docker image format                                                                                                                2292.7s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                             1062.6s 
 => => exporting manifest sha256:87dc5fa88d3dde0e886cf096e4bcae4816c9760d59abf05b8d371e57db5fd0ce                                                      0.0s 
 => => exporting config sha256:370586669b2f3196bfcd33d21188e90e3564bd5b94fc98fd34dfb69543c96e1c                                                        0.0s 
 => => sending tarball                                                                                                                              1230.0s
 => importing to docker                                                                                                                                0.0s
```

The build also takes a long time (20+ mins) each time, so none of the layers appear to be cached.

I've tried building several times, but the image just isn't found. When I try to run it, I get the error:

```
Unable to find image 'platescanimage:python' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: {"progressDetail":{},"errorDetail":{"message":"initializing source docker://platescanimage:python: reading manifest python in docker.io/library/platescanimage: requested access to the resource is denied"},"error":"initializing source docker://platescanimage:python: reading manifest python in docker.io/library/platescanimage: requested access to the resource is denied"}.
See 'docker run --help'.
```